# Unable to position bootstrap elements as needed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, position

I have a tab and some pagination that I want to lay out like this in my JSP:

[image]

So I wrote this JSP:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul id="pagination" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

How can I create the experience I want given that the line thing is part of the tab element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    top: -60px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <nav>
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="active"><span>1 </span></li>
        <li class="active"><span>2 </span></li>
        <li class="active"><span>3 </span></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ytyvr7c5/

Comment: Worked perfectly. I see that the key is using position:absolute. I also had to get rid of a margin that was coming from the plugin, but after that it was smooth sailing. Thanks.